# Why is the value of parameter not redefined in this case?

Tags: javascript

When we take a rest parameter in the parameter list and try to redefine the arguments using `arguments[0]=99999` parameter a is not re-defined

```js
//function defined  

function bar(a, b, c, ...args) {
  arguments[0] = 99999;
  console.log(arguments[0]); //99999
  document.write(a); //20
}

//function call
bar(20);
```

Comment: Because you are not in sloppy mode.

Comment: @Bergi It's actually because of the rest parameter

Comment: @Bergi - It's not strict, the OP is right about the rest parameter.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, it's not exactly `"use strict"` mode, but as soon as you use modern syntax it implies the same features as strict mode.

Comment: @Bergi - Not the same features, no, it just affects the `arguments` link as far as I can tell (https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation). See the snippet I put in CertainPerformance's answer, which happily falls into the implicit global trap (which it couldn't in strict mode).

Answer (score 3):

When you use rest syntax, you do not have what the specification calls a "simple parameter list", which you can find [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function-definitions-static-semantics-issimpleparameterlist):

> 14.1.13 Static Semantics: IsSimpleParameterList
>
> (If the syntax is) FormalParameters:FormalParameterList, **FunctionRestParameter**
>
> 1. **Return false.**

And, as you can see in [9.2.10 FunctionDeclarationInstantiation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation), when you don't have a IsSimpleParameterList, the following is run:

> 22. If argumentsObjectNeeded is true, then
>
>     a. If strict is true or if simpleParameterList is false, then
>
>     1. Let ao be `CreateUnmappedArgumentsObject(argumentsList)`.
>
>     b. Else
>
>     1. Let ao be `CreateMappedArgumentsObject(func, formals, argumentsList, envRec)`.

If you're in strict mode *or* there are any rest parameters, the arguments object is not linked to the argument names, as described in Create**Un**mappedArgumentsObject. Otherwise, a "mapped" arguments object is created, in which case reassigning one of the `arguments` properties will result in the parameter being reassigned.

Here's an example showing that having the rest parameter prevents the link between `arguments` and the formal parameters, but doesn't make the function strict:

```js
function looseFunction(a) {
    arguments[0] = "changed";
    console.log(arguments[0]); // "changed"
    console.log(a);            // "changed", because `arguments` is linked to `a`
}
function looseFunctionWithoutLink(a, ...rest) {
    arguments[0] = "changed";
    console.log(arguments[0]); // "changed"
    console.log(a);            // "original", because `arguments` is not linked
                               // to `a`
    foo = 42;                  // Not an error (it would be in strict mode)
                               // assigning to an undeclared identifier
    console.log(foo);          // 42
}
looseFunction("original");
looseFunctionWithoutLink("original");
```

Comment: Okay if I just move my stack snippet into your answer and delete mine? I think the snippet is useful...

Comment: Sure, go ahead.